# Spring boot - Initialize bean which is dependent on user input

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot and came across a case where say I have two beans

1. `Parent Bean` which depends on input `uniqueFamilyCode` for initialization.
2. I have another bean `Child Bean` which depends on the `Parent Bean` for functionality.

Below is the snippet for `Parent Bean`

```
package com.example.springdemo;

public class Parent {

    String uniqueFamilyCode;

    public Parent(String uniqueFamilyCode){
        this.uniqueFamilyCode = uniqueFamilyCode;
    }
}
```

Below is the snippet of `Child bean`

```
package com.example.springdemo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


public class Child {

    Parent parent;
    public Child(Parent parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getFamilyCode(){
        return this.parent.uniqueFamilyCode;
    }

}
```

Now I want to manage it via Spring boot so I created a `Configuration class` like below

```
package com.example.springdemo;


import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

public class FamilyConfig {

    @Bean
    public Child getChild(Parent parent){

        return new Child(parent);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public Parent getParent(String name){ --> At this point intelliJ showing me error No bean of string type found

        return new Parent(name);
    }

}
```

My question is, how do I manage the `Parent` Bean in Spring Boot Way.

**My Analysis**

`Child Bean` depends on `Parent Bean` and `Parent Bean` depends on user input `uniqueFamilyCode`.

So spring boot at start-up time, can not initialize the `Parent Bean`, hence `Child Bean` also can not be initialized or any other that belongs to this graph.

If it is so, spring boot isn't good for such use cases or there are features to tackle such cases.

Comment: If it's user input, it probably shouldn't be a constructor parameter. Try to rewrite your Parent and Child so they can be constructed without the input, and pass the parameter to their method(s).

Comment: How is the user input provided? Is it entered using some controller, is it entered from the console or something else? Can it change during the lifetime of your application?

Comment: @dan1st : You can say it is input parameter via args ( console )

Comment: Are you using a system property? Did you try injecting [`ApplicationArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html) to `getParent`?

Comment: @dan1st : Can you please elaborate on this one ..

Comment: @Jorn : Making sense, if it is user input, it should not be the constructor rather it could be setter method. Let me try this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ApplicationArguments`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html) for accessing arguments to your Spring application.

An instance of this class is registered as a Spring bean and you can use it to access arguments to your application.

```java
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public Parent getParent(ApplicationArguments args){
        String name = args.getNonOptionArgs().get(0);//get the first argument that isn't passed (without -- before it)
        //alternative: if it is passed as --personName=yourPersonName
        String name = args.getOptionValues("personName").get(0);

        return new Parent(name);
    }
```

If the name is passed as a system property, you can use `@Value` instead. In this example, I will assume that that the system property is called `person.name` (you can pass it as a JVM argument `-Dperson.name=yourName`):

```java
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public Parent getParent(@Value("${person.name}") String name){
        return new Parent(name);
    }
```